# Is there a word for a solemn type of happiness, contentedness, or joy?

Tags: single-word-requests, emotions

Consider someone who feels that the world is full of suffering, and they themselves have suffered much, but nonetheless they see the beauty in the world and derive happiness from that beauty. Is there a word to describe that emotion?

Comment: I'd use "contentment." Looks like you already thought of that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another good word here is *[serene](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=%20serene)*.

> 1. Content or composed; untroubled: "She remained serene in the face of her accusers" (Peter Matthiessen).
> 2. Unaffected by disturbance; calm or peaceful: a serene forest. See Synonyms at calm.
> 3. Unclouded; fair: serene skies and a bright blue sea.

Comment: "Serenity" means no more than "calm and peaceful": https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/serenity?q=serenity

Comment: Uhm, I posted what the dictionary said! You don't need to quote another dictionary to me. *scratching head* The first definition is *content* and that does answer the question.

Comment: There is no idea of  happiness in this word; I don't believe so; the idea involved has to do with something like glee or mirth except that it is quiet, not as strong and not expressed boisterously. I can't find such a term that would amount to that. "Content" means "_happy_ and satisfied".

Comment: I don't think "content" sits well with *someone who feels that the world is full of suffering, and they themselves have suffered much*, because being content normally implies being *satisfied*, as acknowledged. Who in their right mind would be "satisfied" to be surrounded by suffering? (particularly, which they *themselves* have had to endure). But ***serene*** seems likely to be the best word available, since it can often imply ***rising above*** adversity, rather than simply "tolerating" it by being content / satisfied.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It is spoken here of "_solemn joy_" in the face of suffering: https://gloriouspublication.com/solemn-joy-7043a3301944.

Comment: @LPH: That link seems to be just one person's rather peculiar perspective, which I would counter with the *huge* number of written instances of ["**serene Buddha**".](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22serene+buddha%22) And I think most people would probably agree that the Buddha is ***fully aware*** of how much suffering there is in the world (not sure if it's conventionally assumed that the Buddha him/her/itself has suffered, but that needn't be an issue here).

Comment: @FumbleFingers It seems to me that this typical of the true christian's outlook (ideally, that is, as christian "theory" would have it).

Comment: @LPH: Xtianity covers a huge range - some manifestations of it are all fire & brimstone and suffering, where others are much more concerned with joy and celebration. Buddhism seems somewhat "simpler" to me, but that might just be because I'm firmly "encultured" in the Judeo-Christian tradition, and I don't know so much about Buddhism.

Comment: (My original thought here was ***stoic***, but that lacks the "positive" aspects of ***serene*** and ***content***.)

Comment: @LPH You described exactly what I'm looking for in your first comment.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree, stoic comes close, but it lacks the positive aspect.

Answer (score 0):

**Nirvana**, the Buddhist doctrine, seems to cover this well.

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nirvana_(Buddhism)&ved=2ahUKEwiF6fCYhb7vAhXGb30KHT9VAu0QFjAnegQIRxAC&usg=AOvVaw2CPeCErgxVgyvY_JP80cA_